# stacked violin plot of Seurat object

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTh6m.jpg)I made a stacked violin plot with 16 different clusters. I have also attached the figure.
Here is the code:

```
    modify_vlnplot<- function(obj, feature, pt.size = 0,
plot.margin = unit(c(-0.75, 0, -0.75, 0), "cm"),
...) {
p<- VlnPlot(obj, features = feature, pt.size = pt.size, ... ) +
xlab("") + ylab(feature) + ggtitle("") +
theme(legend.position = "none",
axis.text.x = element_blank(),
axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1), angle = 0),
axis.text.y = element_text(size = rel(1)),
plot.margin = plot.margin )
return(p)
}
extract_max<- function(p){
ymax<- max(ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range)
return(ceiling(ymax))
}
StackedVlnPlot<- function(obj, features,
pt.size = 0,
plot.margin = unit(c(-0.75, 0, -0.75, 0), "cm"),
...) {
plot_list<- purrr::map(features, function(x) modify_vlnplot(obj = obj,feature = x, ...))


plot_list[[length(plot_list)]]<- plot_list[[length(plot_list)]] +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),
axis.ticks.x = element_line())

#change the y-axis tick to only max value
ymaxs<- purrr::map_dbl(plot_list, extract_max)
plot_list<- purrr::map2(plot_list, ymaxs, function(x,y) x +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(y)) +
expand_limits(y = y))
p<- patchwork::wrap_plots(plotlist = plot_list, ncol = 1)
return(p)
}
StackedVlnPlot(obj = S1, features = features)

#Stacked violine plots
```

Now, I want to make a plot with 5 columns instead of 16 columns. Four selected clusters/columns and one last column containing total/average expression of rest (12) of clusters. Please tell me how I can do this. Thanks in advance, looking forward to a positive response.

Comment: You should add a sample of `features` to reproduce your code.

Comment: Seurat's [VlnPlot() function](https://rdrr.io/cran/Seurat/man/VlnPlot.html) has now a parameter "stack=TRUE" that spares you some custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are features:
features<- c("ENSORLG00000016928","ENSORLG00000028255","ENSORLG00000026984","ENSORLG00000025723","ENSORLG00000004844","ENSORLG00000003048","ENSORLG00000017445","ENSORLG00000012186","ENSORLG00000007143","ENSORLG00000024026","ENSORLG00000016860","ENSORLG00000013986","ENSORLG00000002500","ENSORLG00000021874","ENSORLG00000029444")